# flickering and erasing of the last image drawn in surfaceview of android

Tags: android

What I want to do is to draw an image when the touch is down and when it is moving the image should also move along with the finger and when the touch is up the image should remain in that position. Again if i put the finger down  another copy of that same image should again appear in the touch down co-ordinates and the process continues. 
  I saw many tutorials and tried everything. I tried to save the image of the canvas when the finger is down and when it moves clear the screen with the image saved during the finger down but that did not work. Then, I tried to clear the canvas with black color and paste the image saved during finger down and then draw the new image that I want to appear but still it did not work properly. It causes flickering and sometimes when lift up my finger and then again put it down the last image gets erased.
This is my code:

```
public class renderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    boolean isRunning=false;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Thread t=null;
    Bitmap img;
    Paint paint;
    Canvas canvas2,canvas3;
    Bitmap cache,backup,cache2;
    float x,y;
    boolean up,down,move;
    boolean dummy;

    public renderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        isRunning=true;
        holder = getHolder();
        img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        paint= new Paint();
        x=y=0;
        cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 800, Config.ARGB_8888);
        cache2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 800, Config.ARGB_8888);
        backup = Bitmap.createBitmap(600,800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas2 = new Canvas(cache);
        canvas3 =new Canvas(cache2);

        move=down=false;
        up=true;
        dummy=false;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("status","run");
        while(isRunning){
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }

             Canvas canvas1 = holder.lockCanvas();

            canvas1.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas1.drawBitmap(cache2,0,0,paint);
            canvas1.drawBitmap(cache,0,0,paint);

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas1);

        }
    }



    public void pause(){
        isRunning = false;
        while(true){
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        }
        t=null;
    }


    public void resume(){
        isRunning=true;
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void down(float posX, float posY) {

        /*x=posX;
        y=posY;*/

        canvas2.drawBitmap(img,posX,posY,paint);
        canvas3.drawBitmap(img,posX,posY,paint);
        up=false;
    }
    public void move(float posX, float posY) {

        move=true;
        dummy=true;

        canvas2.drawColor(Color.BLACK); 
        canvas2.drawBitmap(cache2, 0, 0,paint);
        canvas2.drawBitmap(img,posX,posY,paint);


    }

    public void up(float posX, float posY) {
        up=true;

        move=false;
        canvas2.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas2.drawBitmap(cache2,0,0,paint);

        canvas2.drawBitmap(img,posX,posY,paint);
    }


}
```